# Having a M:M and 1:M between same tables

Tags: entity-framework

I have 2 entities. One is `Team` and another is `Company`. One Team can belong to multiple companies and one Company can belong to multiple teams.

So using entity framework i have established a M:M relationship between `Team` and `Company`.

A Company can be of different types. Say: `Type-A` and `Type-B`.

Now, Whenever a person who belongs to a Company of Type-A (only Type-A and not Type-B), creates a row in Team, then that persons `CompanyId` along with some other company Id's in the teams table.

So i feel there must also be 1:M relationship between a `Team` and `Company`.

Can anyone suggest me how to have both 1:M and M:M between two same tables?

Comment: can you explain again the part about " then that persons CompanyId along with some other company Id's in the teams table."?

Comment: @LiranBo: Its too complicated. All i can explain is there is a requirement that whenever a new team is created, i need store some company Ids as well.

Comment: Removed MVC tags and tags in title. What's the relationship with MVC here? It's unrelated to what you're asking. Please tag with the language you are using.

Comment: ok so the main problem is creating both M:M and 1:M relation?
what are you using code first or model first?

Comment: @LiranBo: I'm using code first. Problem is I already have the entry public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }, for creation of 1:M i need to have this again... How is dat possible..?

Comment: @Zax it will be easier to explain in a chat

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I'm not fully understanding your wording, but I think my answer precludes the need for me to understand the specifics of types A and B.

If you already have a many-to-many relationship set up, it seems easier to limit the amount of connections you can make (in a specific case) through business logic, rather than extending the data model structure.

Adding a one-to-many relationship would mean that for companies with type A, you want the Teams that belong to it to *only* be owned by that company, as opposed to being linked to multiple companies, correct?

So therefore, you need to **prevent** adding a second company to the same team.
To rephrase again:

- When saving a CompanyTeam (what I assume the intermediary table between Company and Team is called), check if the same team already has CompanyTeam rows.
- If it does, check if that company (linked in the already existing CompanyTeam) is of type A.
- If it is of type A, **reject** the current save action (as a type A company can't associate its teams with other companies.
- *Optional: if the current save action is the same company as the existing linked company, maybe allow the save action to continue?*
- In all other cases (if any step above failed), **allow** the save action to occur.

That seems a solution that makes it so you can't link a Type A company's team to other companies, which is what I assume you want.
If I misunderstood, please clarify and I will correct my answer.